# how to define job execution order in Talend?

Tags: etl, talend

I am new to Talend and I am trying to design a data flow that transfers the data from postgres to neo4j database. I am using the "Talend Open Studio for Big Data" open source tool version 6.2.1 . I need to implement an ordered job flow in which Job1 and Job2 are executed independently  and Job 3 is started if and only if Job1 & Job2 both are completed successfully! 
[image: this is what I have done for now ,using the tRunJob]

I have used the tRunJob component  to implement the order however after executing the flow , I noticed that Job3 does not wait for the completion of 2 previous jobs and starts its execution. What am I doing wrong here? Is this the right way to design ordered and dependent jobs in Talend?

P.S. each of the tRunJobs have their own sub flow for example the User_Import is :

[image: User_Import sub job]

Comment: You can use the *tParallelize* component.

Comment: That component is a part of the Enterprise edition ... that does not exist in the open source edition :(

Answer (score 1):

To manage subjobs synchronization use [tParallelize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4enI.png)

[image: Talend parallelize multi thread]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , but I do not want this to be a serial execution flow. I want it to be parallel since the User_import and Item_import are independent and do not have any intersection with each other. So I want to have a parallel and fast flow.

Comment: @Lina, Updated answer !